# Trying to use the total of related objects' fields in a Django ORM query

Tags: django, django-orm

Suppose I have two models:

```
class Task(Model):
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=100)

class Record(Model):
    minutes_planned = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name=records)
```

I would like to get ahold of all the objects whose total minutes planned across all related Records is lower than the object's duration. I've been having trouble finding a solution in the docs. Could someone point me to it?

```
Task.objects.filter(duration__gt=F('records__minutes_planned')))

Task.objects.filter(duration__gt=Sum('records__minutes_planned'))

Task.objects.filter(duration__gt=Sum(F('records__minutes_planned')))
```

but so far nothing has worked. The first one ran successfully, but from what I can tell, it compared them one-by-one instead of to a total of all records.

It seems Sum is restricted to usage only in `.aggregate()`. However, I would like to retrieve the objects themselves, rather than a set of values, which is what `.aggregate()` would give me.

UPDATE:
Found [this portion the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression) that looks promising.

Comment: first, mistake in `task = models.ForeignKey(Record, related_name=records)`? Its must FK to Task as i know.

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution written as a model Manager:

```
from django.db.models import Manager, OuterRef, Subquery, Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class TaskManager(Manager):

    def eligible_for_planning(self, user):
        from .models import Record
        records = Record.objects.filter(task=OuterRef('pk')).order_by().values('task')
        minutes_planned = records.annotate(total=Sum('minutes_planned')).values('total')
        qs = self.model.objects.filter(user=user, status=ACTIONABLE, duration__gt=Coalesce(Subquery(minutes_planned), 0))
        return qs
```

We're basically constructing a second query to grab the value needed for the first query.

In this case, `records` is the second query (or `SubQuery`), and it filters the Records by the pk of Task being queried in this manager.

Then, `minutes_planned` returns the actual total that will be compared to the Task's `duration`.

Finally, the whole thing is plugged into the queryset as a `Subquery` object. Wrap it in a `Coalesce` and add the default value, should there be no Record objects found. In my case, this is zero.

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate). You can annotate a field which holds the sum of the `minutes_planned` of all the `Records` and then use this value for filtering out the needed `Tasks`. The query will look something like:

```
Task.objects.annotate(total_minutes_planned=Sum('records__minutes_planned')).
   filter(duration__gt=total_minutes_planned)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's the right idea, but implementation is more complicated than this. See the update to the question.